# Receiving nothing after sending HTTP request to server in C language

Tags: c, sockets, http

I would like to create a little downloader in C language. Everything was fine until i wanted to get the content of the web page. Everytime the answer is empty because nothing is displayed. I don't understand why.

I am getting host, port number and path thanks to regex but i am not showing it because SO says that my post is mostly code...

```
#define BUF_SIZE 100

int main (int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  int s;
  int response;
  struct sockaddr_in sin; 
  struct hostent *hptr;

  char * regexHost = "^https?://([^:0-9/]*):?([0-9]*)?(.*)$";
  size_t maxGroups = 4;

  char * host;
  char * port;
  char * path;
  char *request = malloc(256);
  char buf[BUF_SIZE];

  /* Creating socket */
  printf("Creating socket...\n");
  if ( (s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 ) ) < 0) /* create socket*/
    { 
      perror("error on socket\n");  /* socket error */
      return -1;
    }
  else
    {
        printf("Successfully created socket\n");
    }

  sin.sin_family = PF_INET; /*set protocol family to Internet */

  /*Getting host*/
  printf("Getting host...\n");
  if ( (hptr =  gethostbyname(host) ) == NULL)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "gethostname error: %s\n", host);
      return -1;
    }
  else
    {
        printf("Successfully got host\n");
    }

  /* Connect to the server */
  printf("Connecting...\n");
  memcpy( &sin.sin_addr, hptr->h_addr, hptr->h_length);
  if (connect (s, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin) ) < 0 ) 
    {
      perror("error on connect\n"); return -1;   /* connect error */
    }
  else
    {
        printf("Successfully connected\n");
    }

  /* send headers to connection*/
  sprintf(request, ("GET %s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\n"), path, host);
  printf("%s\n", request);

  if( send(s, request, strlen(request), 0) < 0)
    {
      puts("Send failed");
      return 1;
    }
   else
    {
      printf("Successfully sent HTTP fetch request\n");
    }

  while ((response = recv(s, buf, BUF_SIZE-1, 0)) > 0) 
    {
      buf[response] = 0;
      printf("Response : %s\n", buf);
      fputs(buf, stdout);
      memset(buf, 0, BUF_SIZE);
    }

  /* close connection, clean up socket */
  if (close(s) < 0) 
    { 
      perror("error on close");   /* close error */
      return -1;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably need an extra blank line after the Host header, to signify that's the end of your request.

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. Hard-code the host and port if you need to. Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [learn how to debug your code](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Oh and you should probably learn [the HyperText Transfer Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) properly if you want to use it. Or not, and just use some existing [library](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) instead.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you are giving the server a chance to reply. Network is much slower than local processes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [**RFC 7230**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3):

> All HTTP/1.1 messages consist of a start-line followed by a
> sequence    of octets in a format similar to the Internet Message
> Format    [RFC5322]: zero or more header fields (collectively referred
> to as    the "headers" or the "header section"), an empty line
> indicating the    end of the header section, and an optional message
> body.
>
> ```
>  HTTP-message   = start-line
>                   *( header-field CRLF )
>                   CRLF
>                   [ message-body ]
> ```

Notice that after the Start-Line (Additional-Stuff) CRLF there is another CRLF afterward to indicate that here is where the headers end.

So, tack another `"\r\n"` to the end of your request string in the call to `sprintf` that builds it.

Comment: You need to also include a `Connection: close` request header as well. In HTTP 1.1, the default setting is `keep-alive`, which means the server will keep its end of the TCP connection open after sending the response, thus your reading loop will not actually terminate (your loop is the *wrong* way to read an HTTP response, BTW!). Since you want to close your socket after receiving the response, sending `Connection: close` tells the server to close its end of the TCP connection after sending the response (thus allowing your reading loop to terminate).